# Accses to data from IoT Hub Azure with Java

Tags: java, azure, cloud, iot, azure-iot-hub

I send data to the IoT Hub and receive it, it works, but i dont know how i can work with the received Data: here is my Code to receive data:

```
public void accept(PartitionReceiver receiver)
            {
                System.out.println("** Created receiver on partition " + partitionId);
                try {
                    while (true) {
                        Iterable<EventData> receivedEvents = receiver.receive(10).get();
                        int batchSize = 0;
                        if (receivedEvents != null)
                        {
                            for(EventData receivedEvent: receivedEvents)
                            {                                    
                                System.out.println(String.format("| Time: %s", receivedEvent.getSystemProperties().getEnqueuedTime()));
                                System.out.println(String.format("| Device ID: %s", receivedEvent.getProperties().get("iothub-connection-device-id")));
                                System.out.println(String.format("| Message Payload: %s", new String(receivedEvent.getBody(), Charset.defaultCharset())));
                                batchSize++;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    System.out.println("Failed to receive messages: " + e.getMessage());
                }
            }
```

I would like to work with the received data, here I become the data as JSON String:

```
System.out.println(String.format("| Message Payload: %s", new String(receivedEvent.getBody(), Charset.defaultCharset())));
```

The dataoutput is: product: xy, price: 2.3.
I would like take the data to :

```
String product= product;
double price= price;
```

How can I the received Payload save in the variable?

Thanks

Comment: Can you provide more information about how you're trying to receive the data? You may find this article useful which describes both sending and receiving data to IoT Hub using the Java SDK: https://azure.microsoft.com/documentation/articles/iot-hub-java-java-getstarted/

Comment: It works! thanks @ Peter Pan and Domic Betts

Answer (score 2):

There are two kinds of messages which include `device-to-cloud` and `cloud-to-device`.

For the first kind, `device-to-cloud` messages, as @DominicBetts said, you can refer to the section [`Receive device-to-cloud messages`](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/iot-hub-java-java-getstarted/#receive-device-to-cloud-messages) to know how to receive d2c messages with Event Hub-compatible endpoint. And there are two samples as references on GitHub, please see below.

1. [Simple send/receive sample](https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdks/blob/master/java/device/samples/send-receive-sample): Shows how to connect then send and receive messages to and from IoT Hub, passing the protocol of your choices as a parameter.
2. [Simple sample handling messages received](https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdks/blob/master/java/device/samples/handle-messages): : Shows how to connect to IoT Hub and manage messages received from IoT Hub, passing the protocol of your choices as a parameter.

For the second kind, `cloud-to-device` messages, you can refer to the section [`Receiving messages on the simulated device`](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/iot-hub-csharp-csharp-c2d/#receiving-messages-on-the-simulated-device) to know how to receive c2d messages. The sample code in the article was writen for C#, but I think it's simple for using Java instead of C#, please notice the note in the section for choosing the suitable protocol.

Comment: Have you any idea?

Comment: @ofitz Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38028130/how-can-i-work-with-the-received-data-from-azure-iot-hub.